# If I have two keys with equal value, how do I return a Set<String> kinda (value + " - " + key ", " + key)?

Tags: java, set, treemap

This code works only when I have a pair like name(value) + number(key), but I'm stuck with situation like - name + number, number. It returns name + number1, name + number2

```
 public Set<String> getAllContacts() {
        TreeSet<String> contacts = new TreeSet<>();
        if (phoneBook.isEmpty()) {
            return new TreeSet<>();
        } else {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : phoneBook.entrySet()) {
                contacts.add(entry.getValue() + " - " + entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return contacts;
    }
```

Comment: We ould use some clarification on the problem.  What does your source map look like?  What is your expected output?

Comment: Your `Map` can only contain one entry per key. You cannot have multiple numbers per name, that is a limitation of your input `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to invert `key` and `value` of your `phoneBook` map. Since one `name` can have multiple `number`s according to your example the output structure should be `Map<String, List<String>>`. With this name oriented phone book you can easily create your contact collection. E.g.

```
Map<String, List<String>> phoneBookByName = new HashMap<>();
phoneBook.forEach((k, v) -> {
    List<String> numbers = phoneBookByName.computeIfAbsent(k, s -> new ArrayList<>());
    numbers.add(v);
});
TreeSet<String> contacts = new TreeSet<>();
phoneBookByName.forEach((k, v) -> contacts.add(k + " - " + String.join(", ", v)));
return contacts;
```

or using streams

```
Map<String, List<String>> phoneBookByName = phoneBook.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
return phoneBookByName.entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + " - " + String.join(", ", entry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```